# Error in deserialize json in C#

Tags: c#, json

here is my Get Set Method Class

```
public class RechargeGridDTO
{

    public String from { get; set; }
    public String to { get; set; }
    public String errormsg { get; set; }
    public String status { get; set; }
    public RechargeInnerMsgGridInfo message { get; set; }
    public String type { get; set; }
    public String reqid { get; set; }
}
public class RechargeInnerMsgGridInfo
{
    public String mob {get;set;}
    public String rctype { get; set; }
    public String rcservice { get; set; }
    public String rcmobile { get; set; }
    public String rcamt { get; set; }
    public String rcpin { get; set; }
    public String mytxid { get; set; }
    public String optxid { get; set; }
    public String txid { get; set; }
    public String rcstatus { get; set; }
    public String rcmsg { get; set; }
    public String rctime { get; set; }
    public String rcbal { get; set; }
    public String rcsimbal { get; set; }
    public String rcremark { get; set; }
    public String rcchnnl { get; set; }
}
```

this is the json response I wanted to parse i-e:

```
msg = {
     "from":"nishantuser",
     "to":"smpp",
     "errormsg":null,
     "status":"s",
     "message":
        {
           "mob":"9999999999",
           "rctype":"Rr",
           "rcservice":"Aircel",
           "rcmobile":"8460149820",
           "rcamt":"20",
           "rcpin":"1234",
           "mytxid":"4850",
           "optxid":GUJNishant123,
           "txid":null,
           "rcstatus":s,
           "rcmsg":null,
           "rctime":null,
           "rcbal":null,
           "rcsimbal":null,
           "rcremark":null,
           "rcchnnl":null
       },
     "type":"RECHARGE",
     "reqid":"4850"
   }
```

when i am parsing this json Response then getting error...

```
var ResponseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RechargeGridDTO>(msg);
```

please give me the solution how i can parse this type of Response in using JsonConvert in C#

Comment: Seriously? You say there is an error but then cannot be bothered to even say what it is?  How can you expect an answer when you do not even provide the most important details?

Answer (score 2):

```
"optxid":GUJNishant123,

"rcstatus":s,
```

Those parts are not valid JSON. Strings need to be quoted:

```
"optxid":"GUJNishant123",

"rcstatus":"s",
```